# Adding to existing struct in c

Tags: c, struct

We are given a struct in our homework assignment in the form of

```
struct student 
{
   char firstName[100];
   char lastName[100];
   char grade[30];
   education level;
};
```

Our goal is to add to this struct using this function:

```
void add(char* student_firstname, char* student_lastname, char* student_grade, char* student_level, struct student* list)
{

}
```

My question is do I need to set the pointers to new variables within the add function or do I need to do something else entirely? I am confused on how to add to a struct.

Comment: Best guess is that you need to `malloc` a struct, and then use `strcpy` to fill it. How it gets added to `list` is unclear, and how `char *student_level` is related to `education level` is unclear.

Comment: "Add to a struct" does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip

Answer (score 0):

You need use pointer to structures.
Example:

```
void add(struct student *s)
{
     strcpy(s->firstname, "somename");
     /* other variables operations here */
}
```

In main:

```
struct student1;

 add(&studen1);
```

I suggest you to try reading some tutorials to better understand. Lot of learning materials available when you search in the internet.